Motivation of the name "generic equidimensionality"
The following is Suslin's generic equidimensionality theorem:

Let $S$ be an affine scheme of finite type over a field. Let $V$ be a closed subscheme of $S\times \mathbb A^n$, $Z$ an effective divisor of $\mathbb A^n$ and $\varphi:S\times Z\to S\times \mathbb A^n$ any morphism over $S$. For every $t\ge 0$ so that $\dim(V) \le n+t$, there exists a map $\Phi: S\times \mathbb A^n\to S\times \mathbb A^n$ over $S$ so that $\left.\Phi\right|_{S\times Z} = \varphi$, and the fibers of the projection $\Phi^{-1}(V)\to \mathbb A^n$ have dimension $\le t$ over the points of $\mathbb A^n\setminus Z$.

I am wondering where the "generic equidimensionality" occurs in the statement. Sources like this thesis seems to claim that it allows us to move cycles $V\subseteq S\times \mathbb A^n$ to one where the map $V\to \Delta^n$ has equidimensional fibers. Can anyone elaborate on that? Thanks!
